# How to grab selected value from changing drop down box php and html

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "Dbconnect.php";
if(isset($_POST['btn_up'])){
  $email = $_POST['sn'];
  if($email == ''){
    echo 'there was an error';
  }else{
    echo $email;
    echo "something happened";
  }
}
var_dump($email);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Admin </title>
</head>
<body>

  <form method='post'>
    <label for="select">School name</label>
    <select name="sn">
        <option value="-" selected data-default>-</option>
        <?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE school = 'sn'");
            while($rowtwo = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rowtwo['email']; ?>"><?php echo $rowtwo['email']; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>

<button type="submit" name='btn_up'>up</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm working on making an admin page, so this is only a section of the code. On the viewers side everything looks right, but when i select a value from the drop down and press "btn_up", the code doesn't save the user email in the variable $email, thats why it checks if it is blank because it is telling me that nothing is being saved to the value. So how can I have it save whatever value is selected from the drop down list?
the var_dump() gave me this error

there was an errorstring(0) ""

Comment: Please include a `var_dump($_POST);` at the beginning of your PHP script, repeat the same process, and show us the output.

Comment: It's a typo `WHERE school = 'sn'` you forgot the `$` sign. Voting to close as such. You're looking for a `sn` string literal. The question doesn't warrant an "answer", per se.

Comment: the sn is its name in the database @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Julie Pelletier I added the var_dump() at the start of the script

Comment: @Nick1615:  I asked specifically for a `var_dump($_POST);` to see what is actually being sent that doesn't match what you're expecting, not just the email.

Comment: @Nick1615 just try print_r($_POST) at the beginning after session_start()

Comment: Fair enough; I made a mistake (I do make them occasionally) Your `'sn'` in the `WHERE` clause was a bit deceiving because the POST array holds the same name.  First off, this line `var_dump($email)` should have thrown you the following notice: `Notice: Undefined variable: email in.. on line x` upon initial page load, when error reporting is on. I've tested your code using the `mysqli_` API with success. You need to check for errors here, via PHP and MySQL. I can't see this failing otherwise.

Comment: I also don't know which MySQL API you're using to connect with neither; `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? Other? and if you did successfully connect.

Comment: The connection to the database is successful, when running the drop down shows a list of users that were in the section selected by the mysql_query, the problem I am having is that the $email variable is NULL/0 (whatever the error_string is telling about it) after I run it, so I'm confused on why it's not grabbing the selected drop down option, no errors pop up when I run that I am aware of, also I am using mysql_ @Fred-ii-

Comment: Values in rows are case-sensitive, should that be the case as are columns when looping over results. I.e.: `email` and `Email` are two different animals. Plus, make sure there are no whitespace in there also. Again, I can't see this failing. You would need to post some example values as well as the db schema. Use error reporting and check for errors via MySQL. Here are a few links http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and apply that to your code/query. Case for emails also. Hard to say here at this point.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#selectnumber').change(function(){
                alert('.val() = ' + $('#selectnumber').val() + '  AND  html() = ' + $('#selectnumber option:selected').html() + '  AND .text() = ' + $('#selectnumber option:selected').text());
            })
        });
    </script>
 <select id="selectnumber">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
            <option value="4">four</option>
        </select>
```

[image: Click to see out put screen]

Thanks... :)